# Ansible: read csv file line by line and render it to template with loop

Tags: ansible, newrelic, ansible-template

I am using a csv file to get data and render it to template and copy to remote servers. I am facing issue that CSV file read twice for same server and this results in loop to copy last line in each server instead of 1st line in first server and second on second servers and so on...

test.csv file:

```
Application,env,Datacenter,Hostname
Microsoft,Test,DC1,testserver1
Apple,Test,DC2,testserver2
```

main.yml:

```
- name: read csv
  read_csv:
    path: /u00/app/monitor/test.csv
    key: Hostname
  register: newrelic

- name: Print newrelic var
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname]

- name: copy template
  template:
    src: /u00/ansible/Playbooks/files/infra-config.yml_template
    dest: /u00/app/monitor/infra-config.yml
  loop: "{{ newrelic.list }}"

- name: Start the New Relic Service
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: newrelic-infra.service
    state: started
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```

Template:

```
custom_attributes:
    application : {{ item.Application }}
    env : {{ item.env }}
    datacenter : {{ item.Datacenter }}
log:
 file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```

Expected result is to get first entry in csv in testserver1 and second line in testserver2

```
**ssh admin@testserver1 - **

cat infra-config.yml

custom_attributes:
    application : Microsoft
    env : Test
    datacenter : DC1
log:
 file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log

**ssh admin@testserver2- **

custom_attributes:
    application : Apple
    env : Test
    datacenter : DC2
log:
 file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```

but I am getting

```
**ssh admin@testserver1 -** 

cat infra-config.yml

custom_attributes:
    application : Apple
    env : Test
    datacenter : DC2
log:
 file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
**
ssh admin@testserver2- **

custom_attributes:
    application : Apple
    env : Test
    datacenter : DC2
log:
 file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```

Comment: How does the play know which line from the CSV file the remote host should use?

Comment: Vladimir - That is the actual question. how can i make loop know which line should go to which server. I have Hostname in csv file. can we use condition as per that? point is there will be 100+ servers where this play shall run once we have actual working play.

Comment: Do you really want to read *test.csv* from the remote hosts? If yes, are the files identical? If yes, this doesn't make sense, I think.

Comment: No, files are not identical. each server have different application, DC and env. Ask is to read a file and push this data to remote servers based on list or hostname. when I am reading file as dictionary, its working fine and reading as expected for each server. but when it comes to writing, i get last entry in csv file in my both servers.

Comment: Answer the question, please. Where do you read the file *test.csv* from? By default, the module *read_csv* reads the file from the remote host. Do you read the file *test.csv* from the remote hosts? Or, do you read the file on the controller?

Comment: ideally, I want to read csv from the controller. if its needed to be in remote host, then file can be copied to remote host. (I have tried lookup to read csv from controller but got same output while writing in template)

Answer (score 2):

Given the CSV file on the controller

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.csv 
Application,env,Datacenter,Hostname
Microsoft,Test,DC1,testserver1
Apple,Test,DC2,testserver2
```

The project below

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── infra-config.yml.j2
└── pb.yml

0 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
testserver1 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
testserver2 ansible_host=10.1.0.63

[test:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=admin
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
ansible_perl_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/perl
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - block:
        - read_csv:
            path: /tmp/test.csv
            key: Hostname
          register: newrelic
        - debug:
            var: newrelic
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - template:
        src: infra-config.yml.j2
        dest: /tmp/infra-config.yml
      vars:
        _data: "{{ newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat infra-config.yml.j2 
custom_attributes:
  application : {{ _data.Application }}
  env : {{ _data.env }}
  datacenter : {{ _data.Datacenter }}
log:
  file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```

creates the configuration files at the remote hosts

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [read_csv] ******************************************************************************
ok: [testserver1 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [testserver1 -> localhost] => 
  newrelic:
    changed: false
    dict:
      testserver1:
        Application: Microsoft
        Datacenter: DC1
        Hostname: testserver1
        env: Test
      testserver2:
        Application: Apple
        Datacenter: DC2
        Hostname: testserver2
        env: Test
    failed: false
    list: []

TASK [template] ******************************************************************************
changed: [testserver1]
changed: [testserver2]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
testserver1: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
testserver2: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.61 cat /tmp/infra-config.yml
custom_attributes:
  application : Microsoft
  env : Test
  datacenter : DC1
log:
  file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.63 cat /tmp/infra-config.yml
custom_attributes:
  application : Apple
  env : Test
  datacenter : DC2
log:
  file: /u00/app/monitor/infra.log
```